# How to open a form within a form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Parent form and i like to open a child form within the the parent form.

Can this be done? If yes please reply me with sample code .

Thanks !

Comment: Do you mean just opening the child form using childform.ShowDialog() or appending or placing a childform inside the parent form????

Comment: @dia I like to place childform inside the parent form. If it can be done please reply with the sample code.

Comment: I added the answer for your requirement....

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Following is the code to do what you want:

Assume that button1 is in the parent form.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.IsMdiContainer = true;
            Form Form2 = new Form();
            Form2.MdiParent = this;
            Form2.Show();
        }
```

Also the following link will provide you more better details of what you want to do:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/mdiformstutorial.aspx

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 7):

I note that *all the answers here assume the OP intended to use MDI Form architecture*, although that's never explicitly stated.

And there is another way a Form can be made a 'Child' of another Form: by simply setting its 'TopLevel property to 'False, and then setting its 'Parent property to the other Form.

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.TopLevel = false;
f2.Parent = someOtherForm;
f2.Show();
```

By the way **I think the whole idea of 'Forms within Forms' is a BAD idea**, and MDI Architecture is now, justifiably, deprecated by MS.

Much better, I believe, to make secondary Forms 'Owned, and if you must have other Containers inside a Form, use UserControls, Panels, etc.

Comment: this is a good Answer, especially when someone is working on displaying and hiding multiple panel controls. I liked this!

Answer (score 6):

It depends on what you mean by "within the form".  If you need to have the child form shown as a control of the parent form I guess you could try `ParentForm.Controls.Add(new ChildForm())`.  Or maybe even place the child form in an existing container in the parent form by again using the containing control's `Controls` collection.

HTH

Comment: If you try to do that, you will get exception: `System.ArgumentException: 'Top-level control cannot be added to a control.'`

Answer (score 3):

inform child form that its MdiParent is current form.

MDI:

```
 form2 frm = new form2 ();
    frm.MdiParent = this;
    frm.Show();
```

Answer (score 2):

Modal dialog:

```
var form = new Form1();
form.Parent = this;
form.ShowDialog();
```

MDI child:

```
var newMDIChild = new Form1();
newMDIChild.MdiParent = this;
newMDIChild.Show();
```

Comment: For modal dialog, I got an error on form.Parent = this, but was able to do form.ShowDialog(this)

Answer (score 0):

```
Form child = new Form();
child.MdiParent = this;
child.Show();
```

Write these lines of code in parent form and check.

Answer (score -1):

```
var childform = new  form2();
childform.TopLevel=false;
this.Controls.add(childform);
childform.Show();
```

This works for me.