# how to display form within another form when i click the menu item

Tags: c#, winforms

i'm new to windows application.can anybody help me.here is my doubt.im having one parent form and it has four menu items. when i click any of one menu item ,it should display another form within that parent form itself. how to do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

According to details you ve provided it seems that you need to use `MDI Forms` concept in your app. It s very easy to learn and refer to the following links:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/mdiformstutorial.aspx

[How to open a form within a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434796/how-to-open-a-form-within-a-form/6437206#6437206)

Just include the code in the 2nd link within your menuitem_Click event...

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you could do it.

One simple way for a newcomer is to add the form to the parent form in the designer. Set the visible Property to false (in the properties) so it will not be shown at first when your program is run.
Then you can set the visible property to true when you handle the menu item clicking.

There are code ways to do it too at runtime etc.

[Hers an article with stuff about adding controls (and implicitly child forms) at runtime.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984255%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Inside your main form, add a panel and then use the below method to display the child form.

```
private void InitChildForm(Form childForm, Panel parent)
    {
        childForm.TopLevel = false;
        childForm.Parent = parent;
        childForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;            
        childForm.Show();
        parent.Parent = this;
        parent.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }
```