# Opening and Closing Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have three forms `mainForm`, `LoginForm` and `AdminForm`. on clicking on a menu item on `mainForm` it opens `LoginForm` (using `ShowDialog`) . I want to open `AdminForm` on providing login details correctly but don't want to close `mainForm`.

used this code on `Loginform` to open `AdminForm`

```
this.Hide();
AdminForm adminform = new AdminForm();
adminform.ShowDialog();
this.Close();
```

What it does is,  displays `adminForm` separately. Main form focuses out, I want `adminForm` to appear as dialog on `mainForm` as it does when opening `LoginForm` from `MainForm`.

Comment: What is the exact problem ?

Comment: I didn't really understand the question. but use `Show()` instead of `ShowDialog`

Comment: @CodeJoy i want AdminForm to open within MainForm

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434796/how-to-open-a-form-within-a-form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use ShowDialog you need to pass in the parent form.
So you should do loginForm.ShowDialog(this), then you can do adminForm.ShowDialog(Owner).

Comment: thank you @Nop. this worked ..

        this.Hide();
        AdminForm adminform = new AdminForm();
        adminform.ShowDialog(this);
        this.Close();

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to show `AdminForm` from `MainForm` after `LoginForm` closes.  You can use `LoginForm.DialogResult` to signal to `MainForm` whether login was successful.

```
// in LoginForm, when login is successful:
this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;

// in MainForm:
LoginForm lf = new LoginForm();
DialogResult r = lf.ShowDialog(this);
if (r == DialogResult.OK)
{
    AdminForm adminform = new AdminForm();
    adminform.ShowDialog(this);
}
```

Comment: If adv12's answer solved your problem, click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show admin form in your current form this should work.
You can't show a dialog inside your own form but Show should work fine

```
this.IsMdiContainer = true;
AdminForm adminform = new AdminForm();
adminform.MdiParent = this;
adminform.Show();
```