# Transform Form1 into Form2

Tags: c#

I have a Form1 with a panel on the left side of the Window and I want to make Form2 appear when I click the button "Test" on the right side (where it is the Label "Test"). Is there any possibility or I have to write the code for each new thing I want to put on the right side?
Here is an image:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xjduu.png)

Comment: You should probably use an User Control instead of second Form for Form2

Comment: You could use the designer to add another panel on the right, make it invisible and when they click a button make it visible.  So yes, there is a possibility

Comment: Both ideas work great. Thank you so much.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434796/how-to-open-a-form-within-a-form

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open a form within a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434796/how-to-open-a-form-within-a-form)

Comment: I think you are trying to create a **master/detail** type of form. Search online because there are hundreds of examples and variants depending on the requirements of the application.

Comment: I wanted to "import" all buttons and their position from Form2 exactly on the place where it is the Label "test", in form1. From what I saw, MDI opens Form2, but I have no control where it is positioned. I am now trying to just put all Panels attached to each other (the new one over the previous one) and make each of them visible only when I click a button (as @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp adviced me) . If it doesn't work as I expect, I will try UserControl. I will also check if "a master/detail type of form" can help me as ja72 said. Thank you all, guys. I will come back with updates.

Comment: Also thank you, @ja72. I was unable to mention you above.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a second form, use a [User Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.usercontrol?view=netframework-4.8).
If you are really determined to make a second form appear in your first form, try making the second form a child of the first form using this code inside of the first form's code:

```
  this.IsMdiContainer = true;
    Form2 form = new Form2();
    form.Parent = this;
    form.Show();
```